# Buildpack - saving image: failed to write image to the following tags

Tags: docker, buildpack

I am trying to publish buildpack image to a private OCI repository. I am using `--publish` option. However it fails with following error:

```
ERROR: saving image: failed to write image to the following tags: [java-maven-buildpack:1.0: HEAD https://index.docker.io/v2/library/java-maven-buildpack/blobs/sha256:cfe02c20a60fb987f86a2b5256b0c83cde981919d0953a7645cf2a9e2c7f6357: unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized (HEAD responses have no body, use GET for details)]
```

I am using following command to create and publish buildpack to OCI repository.

```
pack buildpack package  java-maven-buildpack:1.0 --config ./java-maven-buildpack/package.toml --verbose --publish --format "image"
```

Not sure what I am missing. Pointers towards any example or documents would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `--publish` flag with `pack`, you need to make sure that you are authorized to the registry you are publishing to. You can do this via [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).

Also make sure that you have access to the [repository](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/) you are publishing to. For example if you are publishing to docker hub to your personal namespace you probably want something like

`pack buildpack package <hub-user>/java-maven-buildpack:1.0 --config ./java-maven-buildpack/package.toml --verbose --publish --format "image"`

Comment: Thank you @samj1912. I was doing `docker login`. However I had to prefix the buildpack name with our private registry instead of `hub-user`. E.g: I was able to publish with `pack buildpack package <ecr-url>/java-maven-buildpack:1.0 --config ./java-maven-buildpack/package.toml --verbose --publish --format "image"`

Answer (score 1):

Do you own the `java-maven-buildpack` repository on dockerhub ?

If not, I suggest you to push to your own account / repository on Dockerhub, using:

```
pack buildpack package  youraccount/java-maven-buildpack:1.0 --config ./java-maven-buildpack/package.toml --publish
```

Answer (score 0):

To push an image to a private registry you need to follow this steps:

**1. Tag your image like that:**

```sh
docker image tag <local-image>:<image-tag> <registry-host>:<ragistry-port>/<your-name-on-the-registry>/<remote-image-name>:<remote-image-tag>
```

***Example:***

```sh
docker image tag rhel-httpd:latest registry-host:5000/myadmin/rhel-httpd:latest
```

**Notice: In this example the registry is on host named registry-host and listening on port 5000**

After that :

**2. Push your image:**

```sh
docker image push <registry-host>:<ragistry-port>/<your-name-on-the-registry>/<remote-image-name>:<remote-image-tag>
```

***Example:***

```sh
 docker image push registry-host:5000/myadmin/rhel-httpd:latest
```

I hope that this can help you to resolve your Isuue.